# What video port should I get for optimum resolution?

Tags: hdmi, video-adapters, dvi

I have a MSI GTX 970 4G and recently a few pins in the HDMI port broke. The card has 3 other ports: Display Port, Dual link DVI-I and DVI-D.

I sometimes alternate between monitor (1080@60) and TV (2160@60). What cord or adapter would you guys recommend to get maximum bandwidth (2160@60).
My monitor has HDMI and DVI-D and TV only has HDMI.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayPort is the newest and with the highest bandwidth, even compared to the first HDMI 2.0 connections. You won't have problems with 4K@60FPS

Take into account the limitations of the display. If you have an HDMI 1.4 support in your display, then that's will be the limitation, so I guess that in your case, you won't be able to do 4K@60FPS, only 4K@30FPS (which should be good for movies)

DisplayPort:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2 (you probably have 1.2, maybe 1.3, but probably not)

HDMI 2.0:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_2.0

Check the bandwidth difference

Comment: Will I lose any bandwidth if I use a Display Port to HDMI adapter?

Comment: You will be limited by the display HDMI port - what is the exact model of your display? (also, I'll add that to the answer)
EDIT: to reply your question - you won't "lose" bandwidth, you'll just be limited by the port

Comment: I guess that in your case it's probably HDMI version < 2.0, so you won't be able to do 4K@60FPS, only 4K@30FPS (which should be good for movies)

Comment: My TV (LG 55UH615A) supports 4k@60 so it should have HDMI 2.0 port. In that case, I'm guessing I need to make sure that the adapter support it?

Comment: this one should be good https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-DisplayPort-Supports-displays-3840x2160/dp/B00S0C7QO8/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1502409181&sr=1-3&keywords=displayport+to+hdmi+2.0

I have good experience with Plugable and they took the time to explain stuff to me. You can talk to them. It seems that's it's better to get an "active" solution rather than a simple "passive" cable

If you'll scroll down, you'll see their rather detailed explaination

Answer (score 0):

DVI does not support 4k60 so your only option is to **use the display-port**.

As your TV is most likely HDMI only, getting a display-port to hdmi 2.0 adapter is fine as that provides plenty of bandwidth for 4k60.

I recommend using Display-port to hdmi 2.0 for your TV, and using DVI to your monitor so you don't have to switch between the two physically. If not you can just continue to share the hdmi connection from the display-port adapter.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I ordered one which supports HDMI 2.0